# How to target content through css

Tags: css

I have this html that I **cannot edit**:

```
<div id="menu">
 <a href="">Home</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
 <a href="">Meet Our Physicians</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
 <a href="">Services</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
</div>
```

I have to make it responsive and when when on mobile I want to delete the `&nbsp;|&nbsp;`

How can I target it? Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
element{
display:none;
}
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `spaces` for positioning, use margins & padding. Also there are better options for 'dividers' that the `pipe` symbol.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I know, but this is a site that I received to edit and I only have rights to edit the css. Believe me, I would never write that html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to emulate this (CSS cannot target text that is not part of an element, unfortunately), is to target the containing element and then override the styling in the descendant `<a>` elements:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    #menu {
        font-size: 0;
    }
    #menu a {
        font-size: 16px; /* or whatever */
        margin: 0 0.5em; /* or whatever, to restore some spacing between elements */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    #menu > a{
        margin-right: -10px; /* getting the elements closer */
    }
    #menu {
        color: transparent;  /* making the open text's color transparent */
    }
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/bxrf51x3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Maybe something like that:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    #menu {
       text-indent: -9999px;
       font-size: 0px;
    }
    #menu a {
       text-indent: 0px;
       font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```